# How to change checkbox background color in scoped style tag?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, vue.js

I'm using `bootstrap` V4 with `vue.js`

I'm trying to change checkbox's `background-color` blue that is default to green.

but when I do this it worked.

```
 <b-form-checkbox v-model="small">small</b-form-checkbox>


 <style>
    [type=checkbox]:checked+label:before {
        background-color: palegreen !important;
    }

</style>
```

But, when I added `scoped` attribute in style tag:

> <style scoped>

it doesn't work.

And also I read this: 
https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/scoped-css.html and tried

```
<b-form-checkbox class="checkbox" v-model="small">small</b-form-checkbox>


     <style>
        .checkbox:checked+label:before {
            background-color: palegreen !important;
        }

    </style>
```

It doesn't work too.

How to change checkbox background color in scoped style tag?

Comment: In the second one, shouldn't it be .checkbox? I think it is missing a dot.

Comment: @Flink Sorry it's typo I tried this one also.

Comment: why do you need scoped style ? i mean in your case

Comment: you got the solution?